# modify the source for R packages

Tags: r, bioconductor

I want to remove one line:

```
if( nrow(mm) <= ncol(mm) )
```

from a bioconductor package "DEXSeq" How to do that?

Comment: If the change is sensible then maybe it makes sense to ask the `packageDescription('DEXSeq')$Maintainer`, perhaps on the [Bioconductor mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/), to make the change so others can benefit (or so the author can offer a more robust solution to your problem).

Answer (score 6):

An R package is just an archive containing several directories and files. You are free to modify them at will. Download the package -- it will have an ending of the form ".tar.gz". Unpack it; in many systems, the following (from command line) will work:

```
tar xzf package.tar.gz
```

or, if you have the zip Windows version of the package (package.zip), simply unzip it.

Enter the directory that was created, enter the directory "R" and locate the file that contains your function:

```
cd package
cd R
grep "if( nrow(mm) <= ncol(mm) )" *.R
```

edit it, and repack the package again:

```
cd ../..
tar czf package_mine.tar.gz
```

or, in Windows, zip the directory back to the `package.zip` form.

You can install and use package_mine now.

This is not the only way to do it, and canonically one should rebuild the package using R. However, for small modifications and quickly tryin out things it will do.

Comment: Or you can make life easy and use devtools. Have been meaning to writ e tutorial on this, but its basically download source, edit file, `load_all()`.

Comment: Well, yes, you are right, but define "easy life". Learning a few new tricks not only requires spending some time with them, but also remembering them half a year later when you need them again. Whereas modifying a package with tar, vim and standard package tools requires only these tools that you use every day.

Comment: And the reason you don't use devtools every day is...? Possibly because you think its only good for making packages, which it isn't. You can use it to manage any workspace - just put all your R source in a folder called 'R' and use `load_all()` rather than remembering to source the things you've changed and mess up your workspace. Really. Its a good thing.

Comment: I tried this package once and abandoned after a week or so. I don't even consider it to be useful for making packages (maybe I'm too old and got used to create packages using a steam and coal powered relay computer). Yes, what you describe sounds nifty, but is incompatible with my habits.

Comment: I've gone through about five or six different habits in the 20 years I've been S-ing and R-ing. devtools has come on leaps and bounds in the past couple of months. Unless you are six weeks from retirement, give it another go. http://www.rpubs.com/geospacedman/lazydevtools

Comment: Thanks. But I am using windows. So how to convert the source code to a windows-using version zip file?

Comment: @Spacedman well, of course I won't be able to contain myself and will give it another look. It's such a (guilty) pleasure to try out new tricks for the sake of it...

Comment: @user1586241 read the docs on developing R packages in Windows, install all that, then install devtools, then you're done.

Comment: @user1586241 or, alternatively, read the altered answer. In Windows, you use the zipped form of the package, apart from zipping / unzipping, the procedure is the same. Of course, it wouldn't hurt to learn building packages :-)